# Watson Assistant giving error when passing webhook from external server [No Answers anywhere]

Tags: python, json, apache, flask, ibm-watson

I'm Trying to get Watson Assistant to return a JSON response from an external API (Ubuntu 18.04 server) running on Apache2 and Flask for Python. When I test the response in Watson Assistant I get this error `{"response_code":405,"message":"Webhook response is not JSON Object","content_type":"text/html; charset=utf-8"}.`

I've made sure that Flask is passing the response in JSON `response = app.response_class(response=json.dumps(x), status=200, mimetype="application/json")`
And with Apache2

I've searched everywhere and cannot find answer to why Watson is not accepting my JSON.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Change the subject and tags to the question around how to return JSON in your Apache / Flask setup.

Comment: Add some logging in your flask app to verify that the endpoint and return you think is being invoked, is actually being invoked.

Comment: I have the same problem. I prepared a simple PHP server that just logs something to a file. This script is never called from IBM. The error in assistant is the same as above: 405. @gideon-weiss Did you managed to fix it please?

Comment: I am running on the free Lite plan. Can it somehow affect the impossibility to use an external webhook server?

Comment: No, I ended up scrapping the project for other reasons.... still would like to know how to though...

Comment: @deader I have somewhat of a solution... I switched to FastAPI and made a simple POST (GET doesn't work) request and that seems to work. Does require a bit of fiddling to get it to work.

Comment: @gideon-weiss Please, could you share the piece of code with your POST endpoint in FastAPI? Btw. is your api running in IBM cloud or elsewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running this on my own Ubuntu Server. As far as I can tell, Watson Assistant likes your parameters to be parsed like this... A bit unusual.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Params(BaseModel):
    # For your parameters. Eg
    # time: str
    # for non-required. Eg
    # age: int = 0

@app.post("/")
async def root(req_data: Params):
    if req_data.age == 18:
        return {"message": "You are 18!"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works! :) However, I still don't know why my PHP server is not working and this is. I see no difference in the response and headers: 

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo '{"message": "You are 18!"}';
header("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: Ok, finally, I found the problem! My PHP hosting provider was blocking POST request from a foreign IP address (IBM). Oh, such a stupid problem. I changed the hosting's settings and it is working now in PHP too! :)